# Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function -->react component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey I have a little problem in my modal component. The problem is the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: meatState.map is not a function
Any idea what might be causing this? I appreciate help a lot. And also, the meatState is indeed an array.

Modal.js

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import showModal from "../store/meat-context";
import MeatContext from "../store/meat-context";
import CartItem from "./CartItem";
import styles from "./Modal.module.css";

function Modal() {
  const modal = useContext(showModal);
  const { meatState, dispatchMeatState } = useContext(MeatContext);
  if (!modal.showModal) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div className={styles.backdrop}>
      <div className={styles.modal}>
        {meatState.map((meat) => {
          return (
            <CartItem
              name={meat.name}
              price={meat.price}
              id={meat.id}
              description={meat.description}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Modal;
```

Comment: Is initial state really an array? Check that twice. If it is not, set it to `[]`, or write something like `meatState?.map`

Comment: seems that meatState is undefined, check how you are loading that variable at the context, do meatState? check to avoid unexpected exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said `meatState` `must` not be an array. it could be null or undefined.
You can add this code to where you map is to check if this is your issue.

```
{meatState !== undefined && meatState.map((meat) => {
          return (
            <CartItem
              name={meat.name}
              price={meat.price}
              id={meat.id}
              description={meat.description}
            />
          );
        })}
```

or Check the meat state with a useEffect() in your Modal component.

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(meatState)
}, [meatState])
```